# Is there a way I can use JS to close a hanging HTTP request?

Tags: javascript, network-programming

If my web app is incurring [Head-of-line blocking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head-of-line_blocking#In_HTTP) and I'd like  to prioritize incoming requests being blocked, is there a way I can close the blocking requests from JavaScript? Thanks

Comment: What http request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

The handle to xmlHTTPRequestObject (XHR) can be used to invoke [an abort request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/abort). For example, if you want to cancel a request that's already taking a second to run:

```
var xhr=xmlHTTPRequestObject();
xhr.open(...);
xhr.send(...);
...
setTimeout(function(){
  if (xhr) xhr.abort();
},1000);
```

Very important: that an in-flight request is cancelled does not cancel for the server. For example, a request to delete a record might take a long time to respond, but the server will honor the request regardless whether it's aborted or not.

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at the [abort() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/abort)? In theory you can listen for the event and abort the requests.

Also, could you please elaborate further upon your question.